# Assign data from a DB to variables for shopping cart

Tags: php, html

I want to make a shopping cart using php. First I get data from sql DB table and then add them to a array.Now I want to add these data to a html table.Each row contain a button called 'Add TO Cart'. When I click any button('Add To Cart') only the last item of the array will be added the cart array.What should I do.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `item` WHERE 1";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$k = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row_array;
while($test_row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $row_array[]=$test_row;
    [enter image description here][1]
}
foreach($row_array as $key=>$value){
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo $row_array[$key]['item_id'];
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="' . $row_array[$key]['item_id'] . '" />';
        echo "</td>";

        echo "<td>";
            echo $row_array[$key]['item_name'];

        echo "</td>";

        echo "<td>";
            echo $row_array[$key]['item_category'];

        echo "</td>";

        echo "<td>";

        echo $row_array[$key]['item_price'];
            echo '&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp<input type = "submit" name = "add_to_cart" class = "btn btn-success" value = "Add to cart" />';
        echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}`
```

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…”)` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: What is `WHERE 1` doing in the query?

Comment: "I want to make a shopping cart using php" You probably don't. Off-the-shelf solutions are always going to be better than whatever you can bang together like this. [Magento](http://magento.com) is just one example of many of a full-featured e-commerce platform that you can extensively customize.

Comment: There is no `$key` in the array you are iterating over

Comment: Are you saying the last item is added, or you want the last item added?  Where is it being added?  Where's the code that does the adding of it to the cart?  It seems to me you haven't included everything. Does this successfully output everything you expect from the database?

Comment: if i want to add first item to the cart.so i click the first "Add To Cart" button related to 1st item.But it will add the last item to cart;no matter which button i click.